# Error: The call is Ambigious between the following methods or properties...Need help please

Tags: c#, alias, extern, ambiguity

In my current project, a windows application and not a webpage, I'm taksed with breaking out the sub components of a large project (solution).  Originaly the project was created in Delphi and all the sub components were seporate and ran out of process.  When it got converted to C#, it got combined and all the sub components are now run in process.  This creates too many dependencies and prohibits our agile development efforts when supporting the project for the customer.

We use a common repository for all the functionality used through out the project, 40 plus different components in total not including the component(s) I'm currently breaking up.  I've broken out the individual components from the solution for my chunk of the project and converted them to use the common files and compiled them.  They are now each in their own solution.  I'm down to the last component and it references the previously broken out components.  This is where my problem is...

Since all the components use the same common files, using the same namespace, and all are linked to in the individual projects in thier individul solutions, I'm getting an ambiguity.  How do I solve this??

I've searched the internet for an answer and come up empty.  The closest solution to the issue I found was to use an alias:

extern alias myExemHelper;
using myExemHelper::FS.ExemHelper;

But that doesn't solve the issue.  I've also attempted to reference the component directly in the unit to bypass referencing it in the project.  Same as I would do it in a unit test, but that didn't work either.

In addition, I've consulted with some of the other developers in the office and we are stumped.  How can I NOT expose the common from the referenced components to eliminate the ambiguities??

Thanks for any help you can provide!!

Comment: Don't define the same class in two projects.  It's a recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use common source files. Put the common source files into it's own library and share the compiled library between your projects.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I'm trying to avoid carrying around a lot of superfluous code as the common units are used by many different components and I don't need all the additional functionality. But if that's not possible then I'll be forced to use a common library to complete the break out.